# MySQL get average grouped by intervals

Tags: mysql, charts, average, intervals

I have a xy chart of a power curve. Power on the **y** axis and wind on **x** axis.

I get the values from a MySQL table.

How can I get the average Power between intervals of 1 in thew wind column.

Exemple:

```
Wind | Power
10.2   1245
10.2   1245
9.7    1145
8.7    1001
11.1   1345
9.3    1100
10.6   1284
8       987
5.5     352
...
```

What I need is:

```
Wind | Avg(Power)
0-1    ...
1-2    ... 
2-3    ...
...
```

Thank you in advance

**EDIT:**

Thank you all for your answwers!

For my particular case the wind is always between 0 and 25 m/s. 
The intervals that I need to get the average power from are 0.5.

So:

```
0 - 0,25
0,25 - 0,75
0,75 - 1,25
1,25 - 1,75
... - 25
```

Comment: What is your PRIMARY KEY?

Comment: My primary key is other other field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this in this case it is better to use a `GROUP BY CASE` statement.

```
SELECT CASE 
                WHEN Wind < 1 THEN '0-1'
                WHEN Wind >= 1 AND Wind < 2 THEN '1-2'
                WHEN Wind >= 2 AND Wind < 3 THEN '2-3'
                WHEN Wind >= 3 AND Wind < 4 THEN '3-4'
                WHEN Wind >= 4 AND Wind < 5 THEN '4-5'
                WHEN Wind >= 5 AND Wind < 6 THEN '5-6'
                WHEN Wind >= 6 AND Wind < 7 THEN '6-7'
                WHEN Wind >= 7 AND Wind < 8 THEN '7-8'
                WHEN Wind >= 8 AND Wind < 9 THEN '8-9'
                WHEN Wind >= 9 AND Wind < 10 THEN '9-10'
                WHEN Wind >= 10 AND Wind < 11 THEN '10-11'
                WHEN Wind >= 11 AND Wind < 12 THEN '11-12'
                ELSE 'Other'
            END as Wind,
        AVG(Power) as Power
FROM power
GROUP BY CASE 
                WHEN Wind < 1 THEN '0-1'
                WHEN Wind >= 1 AND Wind < 2 THEN '1-2'
                WHEN Wind >= 2 AND Wind < 3 THEN '2-3'
                WHEN Wind >= 3 AND Wind < 4 THEN '3-4'
                WHEN Wind >= 4 AND Wind < 5 THEN '4-5'
                WHEN Wind >= 5 AND Wind < 6 THEN '5-6'
                WHEN Wind >= 6 AND Wind < 7 THEN '6-7'
                WHEN Wind >= 7 AND Wind < 8 THEN '7-8'
                WHEN Wind >= 8 AND Wind < 9 THEN '8-9'
                WHEN Wind >= 9 AND Wind < 10 THEN '9-10'
                WHEN Wind >= 10 AND Wind < 11 THEN '10-11'
                WHEN Wind >= 11 AND Wind < 12 THEN '11-12'
                ELSE 'Other'
            END
```

This way if you want to change the range that each group covers you can do that fairly easily.

Comment: I try this query with the schema propossed by @Ollie and doesn't works, this shouldn't be the answer

Comment: This answer does work.  I edited my answer to include the `ELSE` clause to pick up any rows that didn't meet the `CASE` statements.  @RobertRozas

Answer (score 3):

This can be an aggregate query in which you use an injective function to categorize your individual observations.  The injective function is `FLOOR(Wind)`.

Here's the query (http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9e64b6/9/0), including the display stuff for ranges.

```
SELECT CONCAT(FLOOR(Wind),'-',FLOOR(Wind)+1) AS Wind, 
       AVG(Power) AS Power
  FROM power
 GROUP BY FLOOR(Wind)
 ORDER BY FLOOR(Wind)
```

This, of course, uses the MySQL `AVG()` function, generating an arithmetic average. I think the kind of application you're working on prefers a geometric average, but I'm not sure about that.

It also yields a sparse result set.

Comment: Yes this answer works for his specific query, but it limits him to a range of 1.  If he wanted to query where the wind is 0-2, 2-4, etc. then this won't work.

Comment: @jayoaK, it's funny because the selected answer doesn't work at all...this answer works based on the OP question.

Comment: @RobertRozas check my answer and run it in the sqlfiddle.  It works, I assure you.

Comment: Edited 11 minutes ago....but now works...but the fact is that this answer works before yours....feel free to add a +1 to this answer xD

Comment: @RobertRozas I did +1 this answer because it does work for the original question, but my answer works as well and is more practical.  Feel free to +1 my answer :)